# How to apply multiple criteria on a parsed csv chunk to get multiple outputs?

Tags: dask

New to dask , Any help is appreciated!
Basically i read csv file out of 540 csv files(out of RAM) & everytime i read a csv i apply 2 filter criteria to get 2 output files, though dask is doing its job , it is taking twice the time for the same chunk. how can i write an efficient code for this.

```
pricing_data = dd.read_csv(os.path.join('Selection Tool', 'prc_data','original','*.csv'),dtype={'BENCHMARK YIELD': 'object',
       'BID YIELD': 'object','SPREAD': 'object'},parse_dates=['PRICING DATE'],assume_missing=True,low_memory=False)

pricing_data['Running_Month_ISIN'] = pricing_data['PRICING DATE'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m%Y'), meta=('PRICING DATE', 'object')) + pricing_data['ISIN']
pricing_data['ISIN_PRICING_DATE'] = pricing_data['ISIN'] + pricing_data['PRICING DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(str)  # master pricing data 
pricing_data['PRICING_DATE_ISIN'] = pricing_data['PRICING DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(str) + pricing_data['ISIN'] 
prc_output2 = pricing_data[pricing_data.PRICING_DATE_ISIN.isin(matching_list_2)].compute()
prc_output1 = pricing_data[pricing_data.Running_Month_ISIN.isin(matching_list_1)].compute()
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#avoid-calling-compute-repeatedly):

> Compute related results with shared computations in a single dask.compute() call
>
> This allows Dask to compute the shared parts of the computation (like the dd.read_csv call above) only once, rather than once per compute call.

So in your case:

```
dask_prc_output2 = pricing_data[pricing_data.PRICING_DATE_ISIN.isin(matching_list_2)]
dask_prc_output1 = pricing_data[pricing_data.Running_Month_ISIN.isin(matching_list_1)]
prc_output1, prc_output2 = dask.compute(dask_prc_output1, dask_prc_output2)
```